# How to connect iPhone's internet to Windows PC via USB cable?

Tags: windows-8, iphone

I have an iPhone 4S. I want to use the internet on my Windows 8 PC from my iPhone via USB cable.

Answer (score 7):

This is how:

1. Install latest iTunes on Windows PC
2. iPhone Settings -> Mobile -> Personal Hotpsot -> ON
3. Select "USB Cable" on window that pops up
4. Connect iPhone to Windows PC

The latest version of iTunes needs to be installed, because that will install the drivers required for Windows to see the iPhone as a modem and use it to bridge a connection to the internet.

Comment: This works but iTunes is >100MB download, which can be a problem if you don't have a broadband connect, which may be the case if you are using your phone as a modem... So does anyone know a way that doesn't require full iTunes?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to install a complete iTunes, you can also just use the drivers from the iTunes installation package as shown here:
http://www.khngai.com/blog/index.php?/archives/620-iPhone-USB-Tethering-without-iTunes.html

This is the basic process:

- Install AppleApplicationSupport.msi (must be installed before AppleMobileDeviceSupport.msi)
- Install AppleMobileDeviceSupport.msi (do not change the installation directory)
- Copy QTCF.dll, QuickTime.qts, QuickTimeVR.qtx (from QuickTime) to C:\Windows\System32\

Ps.: I skipped the third part with coping the files an it works.

Complete details on the link above.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you add in the relevant parts of the link into your answer? We ask this to help the OP out, so they will not have to search through information that may not pertain to them. This is also to preserve the relevant information in case the hosting site goes down. For more information, see this [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259).